# mysql multi-table fulltext query problem?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I am making a multi-table fulltext query.But I met some question.
I need make a query like

```
(SELECT 
title,content,date,cat 
FROM article1 
WHERE 
cat='Science fiction' 
AND 
MATCH (title,content) 
AGAINST 
('+Harry +Potter' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
UNION 
(SELECT 
title,content,date 
FROM article3 
WHERE MATCH (title,content)
 AGAINST 
('+Harry +Potter' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
Order By date DESC LIMIT 10
```

But it caused `Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource`

If I deleted `cat='Science fiction' AND` it can pass the test.

Where is the problem? If I want make a query what I want: first fulltext query require need meet `cat='Science fiction'`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to UNION together result sets that return a different number of columns. Your first query returns 4 columns (title,content,date,cat) while your second only returns 3 (title,content,date). Each query must return the same number of columns.

Answer (score 2):

Did [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) return FALSE, indicating a problem parsing your query? If you blindly passed "FALSE" into mysql_fetch_array(), I'd expect to see that kind of error.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why removing the `cat LIKE 'Science fiction'` makes the query work.  As written, it should not work in either case.  `UNION` requires both parts of the queries to produce the same number of columns with compatible types.  Your `UNION` has 4 columns in the first part and 3 columns in the second:

```
SELECT  title, content, date, cat FROM article1  
UNION
SELECT  title, content, date      FROM article3
```

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli, so how to solve the problem what I meet? If I need a query like this.

Comment: @cj333: add a cat column to the 2nd part of the query.  If there is no appropriate column in article3 to use, then use a constant

Comment: @cj333: If you don't need the cat column in the second query, then modify that second query to be `SELECT title,content,date,NULL AS cat...`

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli, `SELECT title,content,date,NULL AS cat...`, it can run. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
cat LIKE 'Science fiction'
```